# How to automate Mac desktop gui automation

Tags: macos, automation, ui-automation

Till now all the queries i posted on stack got very quick response thanks to every one.

Suppose i have installed gui application on mac platform and that gui when i click button like connect or any action i do , it will interact with the server.

So above action on windows if we do we use autoit for client side operations, similarly i would like to know on mac platform

I came across stack forum few suggested ldtp driver or atomac , pyautogui (but mouse position based on x y which are uncertain). Is it correct one? Does it support all versions of mac? And now instead of writing multiple client side code for windows,mac,linux i want for cross platform too.

I tried atomac but unable to acess child pop window from parent window.

app.windows()[1].findAllR() returns indexerror

Please kindly help me on this. Advance thanks
I posted same question several times  its closed as duplicate. So reposting question
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

this interaction that you need with the Server, I'll recommend the [Back4App](http://back4app.com) and the amazing service provided. For now, you can check the Parse Server Documentation to [macOS](https://docs.parseplatform.org/macos/guide/) and after you just need to replace your keys and the ServerURL pointing to the Back4App side, the correct serverURL is https://parseapi.back4app.com/.

Comment: Thanks for response but the answer you specified doesn't slove my query. Already an application exists on MAC platform want to access that application using python language and want to do keyboard and mouse actions using python language. For example to access TextEdit application and when want to save Text Edit it prompts for textbox , to click on "save button" how to control mouse events and keyboard events using python. Please help me how to achieve it.